# Running form in Oracle Forms 11g gives noclassdeffounderror error

Tags: oracle11g

I have configured webutil in oracle forms 11g then attached webutil object groups and webutil library then call webutil functions for browse and select image file. When running the form,i got noclassdeffounderror.

[image]

However when I run webutil_demo form, i got the required functionality. I don't know what's wrong with my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This exception states that JVM was not able to find any data structure for the definition of a class in its internal class definition. For some reason loading a class from classpath was not successful before and now you are trying to load the class again but JVM learned that it would be an unsuccessful attempt. Please check if the buildtime and runtime classpaths are different or not for your application, I think they will be different, because while compiling the code it finds the class (so you are not getting a prior error), but in the running time it does not find.

Ref: https://airbrake.io/blog/java-exception-handling/noclassdeffounderror